# On packing axisymmetric bodies in 3D

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, packing-and-covering

Consider any 3D body with an axis of rotational symmetry (e.g. cone, cylinder...) and packing the 3d space efficiently with infinitely many copies of this body. Is the following claim valid?

**Claim:** The densest packing with any such body is necessarily such that all units are aligned along or opposite to the same direction

Proving such a claim will greatly limit the possibilities that need to be considered to find the densest packing. The 2D analog of the claim above would involve bodies with a reflection symmetry.

Note: This question was recorded at https://nandacumar.blogspot.com/2019/02/on-packing-with-axi-symmetric-bodies.html

Comment: I'm pretty sure in this general form the claim is false. You can imagine lots of bodies with rotational symmetries that are non-convex, maybe, and for which a packing with unaligned copies is more efficient. This is not an answer, but more like a hunch.

Comment: Thanks. Hopefully, the claim may be more interesting when restricted to convex bodies - and finding counters harder.

Comment: Are you allowing only rotations and translations of the original body, or also dilations? Are you allowing infinite bodies or not? And will you give an example of the packings you have in mind?

Comment: I was considering packing non-dilated copies of a given finite axisymmetric body in 3D.  As an example of a question on densest packings, one could mention the Kepler conjecture.

Comment: Do you require that the shape is invariant under rotation at any angle, or just at some nontrivial angle? (For instance, does a cube count?)

Comment: If you alter your question by replacing "axis of rotational symmetry" with "axis of revolution", your Claim would have a much better chance of being correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your claim is false for axially-symmetric ellipsoids: when restricted to all have their axis of symmetry in the same direction, they cannot pack more densely than spheres (in terms of volume fraction). However, they can in fact pack more densely than spheres, as discussed in [Donev et al](https://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.92.255506) and references therein.

Comment: Thanks! The reference says: "By inserting very elongated ellipsoids into cylindrical void channels passing thru the ellipsoidal analogs of the densest ordered sphere packings (an affinely deformed face-centered cubic or hexagonal close packed lattice), congruent ellipsoid packings can be made with density > 0.7405 (density of affinely deformed fcc or hcp) (for) thin ellipsoids of revolution" - and these inserted ellipsoids will have a different orientation from the ones in the 'main lattice'. Guess if the orientations of all units *should* be same, one can't do better than fcc or hcp.

Comment: @NandakumarR That's right. If orientation of all units is the same then an affine transformation makes the packing into a sphere packing so can't have larger density than fcc. The paper I referenced shows that even ellipsoids that are nearly spherical can pack more densely than spheres.

Comment: Guess this shows how special Kepler conjecture is!

Answer (score 3):

As a supplementary answer, here are some notes on the 2D analog mentioned in the original post.

The conjecture is false for nonconvex bodies:

[image]

The above shape can tile the plane without gaps when rotated, but allowing only $180^\circ$ rotations does not permit this.

However, if we restrict to centrally symmetric convex shapes (a slightly different condition than reflectional symmetry, but another reasonable analog of rotational symmetry for 2D bodies) then it *is* true: a theorem of L. Fejes Tóth from 1949 states that any centrally-symmetric 2D body has a packing density equal to its translational packing denity, as shown in paper [*Some packing and covering theorems*](http://acta.bibl.u-szeged.hu/13588/1/math_012_pars_a_062-067.pdf). (He mentions in footnote 8 that this result may have been independently given in an October 1949 lecture of K. Mahler.)

Comment: For reflection symmetric convex planar shapes, I would guess at least one of these pentagon tilings is a counter example: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:P5-type4_p4g.png https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:P5-type3_p3m1.png https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:P5-type5_p6m.png

Comment: I had only thought of convex bodies, even in 2D. But the example with those 'hourglass' nonconvex shapes is interesting!

Answer (score 2):

There is another, relevant and older publication on this very topic, with a construction much similar to the one in the article cited by Yoav Callus in his answer above:

Bezdek, A., Kuperberg, W., *Packing Euclidean space with congruent cylinders and with congruent ellipsoids.* Applied geometry and discrete mathematics, 71–80,
DIMACS Ser. Discrete Math. Theoret. Comput. Sci., 4, Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, RI, 1991, MR1116339.

Comment: Thank you! Since the 'basic' claim that all units have one of two mutually opposite orientations is clearly invalid, a natural 'relaxation' would be to ask if there is an *upper bound* on the number of orientations in the best pack of any 3d body with rotational symmetry.